# Setting up Elastic APM .Net Agent in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: elastic-apm

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a custom implementation to the Elastic APM .Net Agent code. Does anyone know how to set it up in Visual Studio 2019? Any references that I could use to refer on setting it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initially asked this questions because Visual Studio did not show the source as expected in the editor. So what I did was clicked Build after right clicking on the .sln (solution) then noticed that necessary version of .Net SDK was not there and version of MSBuild related to it. Once I updated Visual Studio the sources were visible. Hope this would help if someone faced a similar situation.